# ¿Cómo funciona esta variedad de print()?

Tags: python

buen dia,queria saber si alguien podría explicarme como funciona o la lógica del método de printeo (`"%s %s\n" %(nombre,valor)`) que se encuentra en la cuarta linea.
saludos.

```
agenda={"Juan":14253 , "Mariano": 24875 , "Marcos":65232}
with open("agendaarchivo.txt", "w") as agendaarchivo:
    for nombre, valor  in agenda.items():
        agendaarchivo.write("%s %s\n" %(nombre, valor))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero aclarar que esa sintaxis, aunque se parece mucho al `printf()` del lenguaje C, en realidad no está relacionada con `print()` ni con `write()` ni con ninguna otra operación de entrada-salida.

En este contexto `%` es en realidad un **operador de cadenas**, llamado *interpolación de cadenas* (aunque en otros contextos `%` puede ser también el operador *modulo*, si a ambos lados aparecen números). Su sintaxis genérica como interpolador de cadenas es:

```
cadena % tupla
```

Y lo que produce como resultado es otra cadena en la cual ciertas partes de la `cadena` original han sido sustituidos por los valores de la `tupla`. Los lugares a sustituir van marcados por un `%` seguido de una letra, dentro de la `cadena` original, y se reemplazan por los de la tupla según el orden de aparición. La letra especifica el "tipo" del formato. Es habitual usar `%s` que significa "formatear como cadena", pues aunque el correspondiente elemento de la tupla no sea realmente una cadena, prácticamente cualquier tipo se puede convertir en cadena (python se ocupa de invocar `str()` sobre el valor cuando el formato es `%s`).

La cadena resultante de la interpolación en este caso se pasa como parámetro a `write()`. Es muy común también verlo como un parámetro de `print()`. Pero realmente, al tratarse de una cadena, puedes hacer cualquier otra cosa con ese resultado, como guardarlo en otra variable o retornarlo como resultado de una función.

La interpolación de cadenas se considera un mecanismo de generar cadenas un poco antiguo, siendo las versiones más modernas las siguientes:

- `cadena.format()`. En este caso no se usan `%` para marcar los lugares, sino llaves. Y los elementos a sustituir serían los parámetros de `format()`. En tu caso por tanto se vería así:

  ```
  agendaarchivo.write("{} {}\n".format(nombre, valor))
  ```
- f-strings. En este caso la cadena lleva una `f` delante (antes de la comilla de apertura) y en su interior pueden aparecer entre llaves cualquier expresión python, lo que incluye nombres de variables, y esas llaves se sustituirán por el resultado de evaluar la expresión. En tu caso por tanto:

  ```
  agendaarchivo.write(f"{nombre} {valor}\n")
  ```

Las f-strings han ganado mucha popularidad por ser mucho más legibles, pero necesitarás una versión de ptyhon igual o superior a la 3.6.

Comment: muchas gracias por las respuestas, me quedo clarísimo, saludos.

Comment: @GianidaSilva, si esta respuesta resuelve tus dudas, puedes mostrar tu agradecimiento marcando la respuesta como aceptada. Así, quienes visiten esta página en el futuro pueden ver cuál fue la respuesta que te ayudó :)

Answer (score 2):

Es una forma de formatear un String para agregarle variables.
Cuando pones "%s" estas indicando que ahí va una variable que insertar al String.
Después, cuando escribes "%(nombre, valor)" estas indicando la tupla en la cual estas almacenando las variables que quieres insertar en el String.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno es otra opción de construir strings donde %s representa que ahí va a ir una variable de tipos string, %d variable de tipo numérico, y para asociar el valor, se debe poner por fuera del string y seguido de % , los nombres de las variables en el mismo orden que se van a reemplazar en el string. Es una forma cómoda para no estar concatenando muchos strings.